# Remove pale-effect on NSStatusBarButton

Tags: swift, xcode, nsbutton, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

I'm looking for a way to remove the pale effect from the NSStatusBarButton. This is a picture of how it currently looks:

[image: NSStatusBarButton with pale image]

This is how it should look:

[image: NSStatusBarButton with original image]

After looking at Apple's documentation, I found a solution to the problem. If you set the appearance of the button directly (e.g. Aqua or DarkAqua), the pale effect disappears:

```
if let button = statusBarItem.button {
    ...
    button.appearance = NSAppearance.current // or aqua / darkAqua
}
```

But the problem is when the user changes the interface theme (e.g. from dark mode to light mode), the NSStatusBarButton does not change its appearance automatically:

[image: NSStatusBarButton does not change the appearance automatically]

I could monitor `AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification` and then change the appearance, but that's not a clean solution and I'm not happy with it.

Is there an elegant solution to this? The image in the NSStatusBarButton should simply be displayed without changes (e.g. pale). Because I offer all flags of the world, I only have the images in png format, no PDF images.

Answer (score 1):

Since the solution of vadian, unfortunately, did not work for me, I would like to show my alternative solution here. Maybe it helps somebody else.

Create the `NSStatusItem` and customize `NSStatusBarButton`:

```
...
if let button = statusBarItem.button {
    ...
    button.appearance = NSAppearance.current // removes the pale effect
}
...
```

Write an extension for `Notification.Name` to react on `AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification`:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification = Notification.Name("AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification")
}
```

Add an Observer to the new notification name:

```
DistributedNotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(interfaceChanged), name: .AppleInterfaceThemeChangedNotification, object: nil)
```

Respond to the change between light/dark mode:

```
@objc private static func interfaceChanged() {
    // change button.appearance
}
```

Make sure that `button.appearance` is only changed if the necessary macOS version is available:

```
guard #available(OSX 10.14, *) else {
    return
}
```

I am sure that there is a cleaner solution. If anyone has an idea, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Write an extension of `NSStatusBarButton` and override `viewDidChangeEffectiveAppearance`.

In the body of the method change the appearance explicitly

```
extension NSStatusBarButton { 
    @available(macOS 10.14, *)
    override public func viewDidChangeEffectiveAppearance() {
        print("viewDidChangeEffectiveAppearance")
        self.appearance = .current 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Unfortunately, the overwritten method `viewDidChangeEffectiveAppearance()` is only called when creating the NSStatusBarButton (2 times). When I switch my Mac from Light Mode to Dark Mode, the method is not called. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: No, I'm using the method in one of my projects with success.

Comment: I have created a test project. In AppDelegate I set `var item = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)` global, in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` I set `item.button?.title = "Test"` and put your extension at the end of the AppDelegate file. Then I restarted Xcode and ran the project, result: as described in my first comment. The Swift version is 5. Are you sure that the code works in your project? Unfortunately the overwritten method is not explained in detail in Apple's documentation...